# Keep image properties in iteration function in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, iteration, landsat-5

I'm very new to GEE and programming in general. I have this [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5dbff0582425f6d607ca21ca9a637c77) that filters Landsat 5 imagery, creates a collection of NDVI layers, clips the NDVI layers, and creates mosaics of two NDVI layers of the same date. I would like to keep the original name of the image (for example, LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2/LT05_039037_20010106) but when the images pass through the iterate function they lose all of their properties.

Here is the first part of the code:

```
// filtrar imagenes landsat 5
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2').filterDate(start, finish).filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',39)).filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains('WRS_ROW', 37, 38));

// NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
var ndvi = dataset.map(addNDVI);
var ndvi = ndvi.select(['NDVI']);

// Clip al area de estudio
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(DR014);
};
var clip = ndvi.map(clipToCol);
```

This is the part of the code where the images lose all of their properties:

```
// mosaico NDVI por fecha
var diff = finish.difference(start, 'day');

var range = ee.List.sequence(0, diff.subtract(1)).map(function(day){
  return start.advance(day,'day')});

var day_mosaics = function(date, newlist) {
  date = ee.Date(date);
  newlist = ee.List(newlist);
  var filtered = clip.filterDate(date, date.advance(1,'day'));
  var image = ee.Image(filtered.mosaic()).set({date:date});
  return ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), newlist.add(image), newlist));
};
var mosaico = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(range.iterate(day_mosaics, ee.List([]))));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are losing all of your properties in your `iterate` function. What you want to do is tell it explicitly to keep the date property, like this:

```
var image = ee.Image(filtered.mosaic()).set({date:date});
```

Then, in the same loop where you are clipping your image collection, you can use that date to rename your images (well the image *band*):

```
var clipToCol = function(image){
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('date'))
  return image.clip(DR014).rename(date.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
};
```

I chose that format arbitrarily, but you can choose [other formats](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-date-format).

On a separate note, clipping image collections, especially large ones is **generally discouraged**. It wastes computation time and is not necessary. I suggest you read this [Coding Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#if-you-dont-need-to-clip,-dont-use-clip) guide for GEE.

Comment: Also, use .filterBounds(DR014) instead of filtering by 'WRS_PATH' and 'WRS_ROW', it'll save you the effort of finding the path and row IDs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did what you suggested and the bands were renamed, however, now I can't visualize them on the map and this error appears (x21):

Layer 2: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered:
  First image type: 1 bands ([2001-01-06]).
Current image type: 1 bands ([2001-01-22]).
          Image ID: 1
Some bands might require explicit casts.

Here's the "corrected" code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3cdc0acdbd660a8a17a7e09d31a1413e